# Displaying image from NSObject

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview, uiimage, nsobject

I can't get my head around how to add an image to a `NSObject` and then display it in a `viewController`. I have a `NSObject` with a bunch of strings which are shown in the labels of a `viewController` and would like to add an image in an `UIImageView` which I added via the `storyboard`. How can I do this? I'm really confused about how to use `UIImage` and `UImageView`, I have added the images to my `assets`.

Here's my "testing" code - it doesn't work:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

 class myobject: NSObject {
        var String1 : String
        var String2  : String
        var uiimage : UIImage

        init(String1 : String, String2 : String, uiimage : UIImage
            ) {
            self.String1 = String1
            self.String2 = String2
            self.uiimage = uiimage
        }
    }
 let array = [
        array(String1: "test1", String2: "test2", uiimage: UIImage(named:"Buddha")! 
        ),

   ]

    let range: UInt32 = UInt32(array.count)
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))
    let choosen = array[randomNumber]
    let String1c = choosen.String1
    let String2c = choosen.String2
    let imageString = array.uiimage

    self.Label1.text = String1c
    self.Label2.text = String2c

    let imageView =  UIImageView(image: imageString!)
    self.image.image = imageView
```

Thank you, I really appreciate all help :)

Comment: You are creating a `UIImageView` but not adding it to the view controllers view hierarchy. You need something like `view.addSubview(imageView)` (this must be in the view controller). Even then you may not get the layout you expect

Comment: Where is the code at the bottom of your posting being run. I originally thought it was in the VCs `viewDidLoad`, but you're using `self` in a way that seems to imply you're still in `mybobject`

Comment: Incidentally you'll make your life a lot easier if you adopt standard naming conventions in your code - classes are uppercase, variables lowercase - `myobject` should be `MyObject`, `String1` should be `string1`. Not doing this makes the code harder to read and lessens the chance of people making the effort to help

Comment: Thank you for your time, help and tip - they are truly appreciated. I'll keep it in my mind fot next time :) @RichTolley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand you clearly. If you want to add UIImage(image) to UIImageView(imageView), just do this "imageView.image = image". Here is your testing code which is changed by me.

```
import UIKit

class MyObject: NSObject {
    var string1: String
    var string2: String
    var image: UIImage

    init(string1 : String, string2 : String, image: UIImage
        ) {
        self.string1 = string1
        self.string2 = string2
        self.image = image
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let myObject = MyObject(string1: "test1", string2: "test2", image: UIImage(named:"Buddha")!);
        let array = [myObject]

        let range: UInt32 = UInt32(array.count)
        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))
        let choosen = array[randomNumber]
        let choosenStr1 = choosen.string1
        let choosenStr2 = choosen.string2
        let image = choosen.image

        label1.text = choosenStr1
        label2.text = choosenStr2
        // just do this
        imageView.image = image;
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

And I think you should look this 
[UIImageView in apple's document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/)

Comment: WOW, thank you! It works perfectly. I really appreciate your help, have a great day and keep up the good work!